# Applet HttpUrlConnection Chunked Response problem

Tags: java, http, applet

I have an Applet with HttpUrlConnection to IIS 6.0 Server.
Server response chunked data, but sometimes (some browsers) i have a problem.
Server answers stick in certain buffer, and arrive at me when the server close connection by timeout.

```
url = new URL(urlStr); 
huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
huc.setDefaultUseCaches(false); 
huc.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
huc.setDoInput(true);
huc.setUseCaches(false);
huc.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
huc.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
huc.setRequestProperty("Expires", "-1");
huc.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/html");
InputStream is = huc.getInputStream();
... 
while (!trunkStop) {
  while (errorConnection && !trunkStop) {
    connectToServer();
     if (errorConnection) {
       sleepThread();
     }
  }

  while (!errorConnection && !trunkStop) {
            readData();
  }
 ...
}
...
void readData() {
    if (trunkStop) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        readLine();
        addTask();//put to task queue
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(Level.WARNING, "Error connection...");
    }
}
...
String readLine() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    int prev = -1;
    while (!errorConnection && !trunkStop) {
        read = is.read();
        if (read == -1) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 150000) {
                getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "RECONNECT BY TIMEOUT");
                errorConnection = true;
            }
            Thread.sleep(10);
            continue;
        } else if (read == 13) {

        } else if (read == 10 && prev == 13) {
            break;
        } else {
            sb.append((char) read);
            System.out.print((char) read);
        }
        prev = read;
        timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

certain browser buffer, i don't know. 
At this moment IIS already send answers, this is client problem, 
IE7, java 1.6.0_16

Any ideas ?

Comment: Any code to show us?
What do you mean with certain buffer (where is the buffer IIS oder applet)?
Which versions of IIS, Browser(s), Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved!

The client uses a proxy. HTTPS using helped

Answer (score 0):

In `readLine()` you seem to be doing something strange.

When `read==-1` (which means end of stream) you are waiting for 150 secondes before setting `errorConnection=true` which allows  `readLine` and subsequently `readData` and the `while (!errorConnection & !trunkStop) { readData(); }` to stop.

These 150 secondes could be longer than the connection timeout of the IIS server.

---

Btw. you are using the bit-wise and operator (`&`) instead of the logical and operator (`&&`) are you sure that's what you want? Check the difference.

[& java bit-wise and operator](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/andoperator.html)

[&& java McCarthy and operator](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/mccarthyandoperator.html)

Comment: Theoretically, you are right, but in practice when all this is being performed in browser, InputStream can return -1 when the stream is not closed. Especially, when we use https connection. This steam must exsist all the time while the program is running. Server constantly puts data(such as time) into stream.

As for &&, you are right, thanks.

Comment: Danke schon fur Ihre Antwort, ich freue mich! Vienna ist ein schone Stadt